# How to draw a rectangle using WriteableBitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I created a WPF project which just includes an `Image` control.

```xml
<Image 
  x:Name='img'
  Width='256'
  Height='256'
  MouseDown='img_MouseDown' />
```

My goal is to click the image and draw a **10 pixel side square**, of white color, at the specific position where the click happened.

At the begining I tried to draw 1 pixel sized squares and worked as expected.

[image]

Here is that code:

```cs
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        WriteableBitmap wb;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            wb = new WriteableBitmap(256, 256, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);
            img.Source = wb;
        }

        private void img_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = e.GetPosition(img);

            Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect((int)p.X, (int)p.Y, 1, 1);
            int stride = wb.PixelWidth * wb.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
            byte[] buffer = { 255, 255, 255 };
            wb.WritePixels(rect, buffer, stride, 0);
        }
    }
```

Now that I want to draw a 10 pixel size square I am initializing the `rect` with 10 pixels width and height,

```
Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect((int)p.X, (int)p.Y, 10, 10);
```

,but `WritePixels()` throws an Exception saying "*Buffer size is not sufficient.*" Out of desperation I've changed the buffer to have 10 size but still getting the same error.

What is the problem here?

Comment: The `buffer` array must represent the pixel data. You only provide one pixel but that array needs to have 10 x 10 pixels x 3 channels = 300 elements.

Comment: Well I've created a buffer of 300 bytes and I am still getting this error @dymanoid!

Comment: Try with PixelFormats.Bgr32 and 4 bytes/pixel, I had some issues with Bgr24 which disappeared after moving to 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stride` argument is meant to be that of the input buffer, i.e. 3 x 10 here:

```
var width = 10;
var height = 10;
var stride = (width * wb.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
var rect = new Int32Rect((int)p.X, (int)p.Y, width, height);
var buffer = Enumerable.Range(0, stride * height).Select(i => (byte)255).ToArray();
wb.WritePixels(rect, buffer, stride, 0);
```

Comment: Ok I was calculating the stride of the whole bitmap right?

Comment: Yes, you need the stride of the input buffer. See the answer for the general way to calculate it.